VS Code (Mac) view jump down in script when creating new line
I have a script that is more than 1000 lines of c# code.
Every time I create a new line to add some code the view move down so I the empty line that I am about to add code to is not visible. It is just outside the view on top. This also happen when I add a line in the bottom of the script. Even if I do not know exactly when it triggers it does not happen in smaller scripts.
I have tested to disable all the extensions but the problem still exists.
Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Go to File > Preferences > Settings
In Features > Output, disable Smart Scroll option (or search output.smartScroll.enabled)

Thanks, but that did not solve the problem.

When I add a character it jumps back and place the new line on the top of the VS Code display.

disable it, go to File -> Preferences -> user settings
On the right side of the editor in settings.json paste the below line at the bottom , save and close.
"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false
